# Cassandra Spring Data doesn't let me query data by composite primary key directly

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-data, composite-key, spring-data-cassandra

I am trying to use Spring Data Cassandra using Composite primary key class. But when I try to query data I get an exception:

```
org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryCreationException: **Could not create query for public abstract java.util.List com.amdocs.cassandrapoc.repository.ServiceRepository.findByKey(com.amdocs.cassandrapoc.entities.Key)! Reason: Cannot use composite primary key directly. Reference a property of the composite primary key**
```

This is my code:

```
@PrimaryKeyClass
public class Key implements Serializable {

   @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "id", ordinal = 0, type = 
      PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
   @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.UUID)
      private UUID id;
   @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "tenant", ordinal = 1, type = 
      PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
   @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.TEXT)
      private String tenant;
  (Equals, hashcode, getters, setters omitted)
}

Table(value = "service")
public class Service implements Serializable {
   @PrimaryKey
   private Key key;

   @Column
   private String value;
   (constructors, setters, getters omitted)
}

@Repository
public interface ServiceRepository extends CassandraRepository<Service, Key> {

    List<Service> findByKey(Key key);

}
```

This is how I create table (using embedded Cassandra and junit):

```
@Autowired
private CassandraAdminOperations adminTemplate;
private final String DATA_TABLE_NAME = "service";

@Before
public void createTable() {
    adminTemplate.createTable(
            true, CqlIdentifier.of(DATA_TABLE_NAME),
            Service.class, new HashMap<String, Object>());
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: can you add the table definition?

Comment: I use embedded Cassandra and I create table every time in Junit using Service class structure: 

private CassandraAdminOperations adminTemplate;
private final String DATA_TABLE_NAME = "service";
    private final String TENANT = "Test";
 
 @Before
    public void createTable() {
        adminTemplate.createTable(
                true, CqlIdentifier.of(DATA_TABLE_NAME),
                Service.class, new HashMap<String, Object>());
    }

Comment: I edited my original message for a better formatting

Comment: And also I checked with not embedded Cassandra CREATE TABLE service (

id uuid,

tenant text,

value blob,

PRIMARY KEY ((id, tenant))); The same result

Comment: I tried to use standard method from CrudRepository Interface findById(Key key) and it works now.

Comment: `Cannot use composite primary key directly` is currently a limitation of how query mapping is implemented. Looking at your code you could expect exact property matching. There are a lot of other possibilities (`findByKeyGreaterThan`, `findByKeyIn`, dealing with `null` properties in your key) which raise a couple of questions how to deal with these possibilities. Care to file a ticket at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATACASS so we can continue the discussion in our issue tracker?

Answer (score 7):

I faced same issue. I got it resolved in my case with below implementation.

```
@Repository
public interface ServiceRepository extends CassandraRepository<Service, Key> {

    List<Service> findByKeyIdAndKeyTenant(UUID id, String tenant);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use CrudRepository instead of CassandraRepository:

> Repositories based on CassandraRepository can define either a single primary key, use a primary key class or a compound primary key without a primary key class. Types using a compound primary key without a primary key class must use MapId to declare their key value.

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/repository/CassandraRepository.html

Comment: It would help if you would add an example with `MapId`.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter the same issue, but solve using the following implementation style.

```
@Repository
public interface ServiceRepository extends CassandraRepository<Service, Key> {

    List<Service> findByKeyTent(Key key);
    // findBy{PrimaryKey}{PrimaryKeyColumn} format
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I was facing same issue. This was resolved by defining Cassandra Configuration by using AbstractCassandraConfiguration  provided with Cassandra spring framework .

```
@Configuration
@EnableCassandraRepositories(basePackages = "A.B.Z")  // package location of repository
@ComponentScan(value = "X.Y.X")  // enable autowire
public class CassandraConfiguration extends AbstractCassandraConfiguration {

    public String getContactPoints() {
        return "HOTNAME OF CASSANDRA CLUSTER"; // your cluster host 
    }

    @Override
    protected int getPort() {
        return 9042; //default port
    }

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return "YOUR KEY SPACE NAME";  // Cassandra Keyspace Name
    }

}
```